# How to Load Runtime Configuartion for Externally Loaded Module in Angular 16?

Tags: angular

I am able to load runtime configuration in App module but I would like to use same config URL into a different module loaded as package ( not sure If I am saying this right).

This external module is developed as package differenlty and idea is to use different runtime config for this and other modules so that it can be selcted through different environment be it Dev or Production.

Now I have made a small code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/runtime-config-loader-demo-pmekoc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexternal-header%2Fexternal-header.module.ts

This stackblitz is not in working condition but this is almost what the setup is. I have tried APP_INITIALIZER but ExternalHEader is unable to find config from app-configuration service which I have created to resolve a promise for config load.

Sorry for least made code example.